# Code First Migration tries to re-create enitre db instead of updating changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Im trying nto enable Migration with code first but im having some issues.
Im working on a mvc5 website and I have a dll with the datalayer, dll with the domain classes and then the website itself.
I have already run the website and all the tables have been created. Now I change the name of a single property on one of the domain classes and want to update the db. But instead it tries to create everything again!
I change the property, enter add-migration into the console and then the migration file is created, but it contains CreateTable for all my classes instead of just the change for that one table/class.
I have alredy used the console to enable-migration so that should be in order. It created the Migration folder and the Configuration.cs file in my website project.

Here is how my code looks:

```
    internal sealed class Configuration :DbMigrationsConfiguration<Playground.Web.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Playground.Web.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("PlaygroundContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first configure migrations you need to add a baseline migration. If you have existing tables, you need to tell EF to make a no-op migration:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges
```

Now, future migrations will be incremental based on the baseline. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx#option1